# Searching for a value with apostrophe (') using REGEX_CONTAINS

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Simple question, but I can't seem to find an answer specific to BigQuery...

I am trying to search for a specific list of surnames from a table.

```
DECLARE X ARRAY<STRING>;
SET X = {'ALI', 'BAKER', 'COUSLAND', ... , 'O'NEIL', 'WONG'}

SELECT ID, FIRST_NAME, SURNAME
FROM   TABLE
WHERE  SURNAME IN X
```

How would I be able to search for value with an apostrophe?

Thanks.

Comment: Oh, shite.

Just figured it out.


Using / solves it. (e.g. 'O\'Neil')

Comment: I have posted your solution as a community wiki answer to increase its visibility for people with similar issues to yours. Please consider accepting it so that it will be even more visible.

Comment: Hello, Daniel, how would I to that?

Comment: The community wiki answer is posted like a normal answer with the 'community wiki' tag. That tag makes sure that I will not receive any reputation from that answer (because I didn't come up with the solution). Here it is explained how to accept answers: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86979

Answer (score 1):

You can just simply use double quotes instead of single ones as in below example

```
DECLARE X ARRAY<STRING>;
SET X = ['ALI', 'BAKER', 'COUSLAND', ... , "O'NEIL", 'WONG'];

SELECT ID, FIRST_NAME, SURNAME
FROM   TABLE
WHERE  SURNAME IN UNNEST(X)
```

Obviously, you should also note some other corrections in your script - namely:

- Using square brackets instead of curly to set array
- Use of UNNEST in WHERE clause

One more - in [rare] cases if string consists both double and single quotes - you can use triple single quotes to escape those - like `'''abc'xyz"123'''`

Answer (score 1):

The apostrophe can be escaped using a backlash ('\')

```
SET X = {'ALI', 'BAKER', 'COUSLAND', ... , 'O\'NEIL', 'WONG'};
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the values correctly:

```
DECLARE X ARRAY<STRING>;
SET X = {'ALI', 'BAKER', 'COUSLAND', ... , 'O''NEIL', 'WONG'};
```

Then you can use `UNNEST()`:

```
SELECT ID, FIRST_NAME, SURNAME
FROM  TABLE
WHERE SURNAME IN (SELECT el FROM UNNEST(X) el)
```